# android change bounds of google map

Tags: android, maps

I am working on a project in android which requires me to change the bounds of a google map(from bottom only). Currently I am trying by adding padding at the bottom, but this process is slow and the screen also flickers.

Is there any better way to do this?
I would like the user to be able to drag the bottom of the map  to change the bounds.
I see a lot of AJAX/JS resouces, but this is a native component.

Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will be a huge amount of work to let the user actually drag the bottom of your map view. what is much easier and faster to do is to create to 2 map fragments of your map and on click of the map change the fragment back and foreword between the two.

this way the user can change the size of the map the he works with.

Comment: not exactly what i was looking for, but i am accepting your answer as I eventually talked to the designers to change the spec.

Comment: also to remove flickering i might use the 2 map approach.

Comment: yes i know, it's not an ideal solution but at least you will gain most of the functionality you look for.

Answer (score 1):

You can zoom map to added points.
Here is some pseudo code:

```
    LatLngBounds.Builder bc = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

    for (LatLng item : points) {
        bc.include(item);
    }
    LatLngBounds bounds = bc.build();
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds,
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(),
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight(), 50);
    mMap.moveCamera(cu);
```

Bounds will be changed to added points. Help It hope